# .Net MAUI: View not drawing data from ViewModel - Intellisense shows a connection

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, community-toolkit-mvvm

My VIEW refuses to draw data from the VIEWMODEL. The Visual Studio 2022 intellisense fills in the connections as if there is a connection, and it compiles just fine...but no data displays. I've stepped away from XAML for several years, and I'm trying to jump back in.

I am trying to have an entry field update the VIEWMODEL, and then the label to display the text being written to the VIEWMODEL. I keep paring the code back, trying to get ANYTHING to work before trying to execute more complicated bindings, but for now I can't get the VIEW to connect to the VIEWMODEL.

The following XAML is the extremely stripped down VIEW code.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:model="clr-namespace:MauiCalendar.Model"
         xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MauiCalendar.ViewModel"
         x:Class="MauiCalendar.View.DaySingleView"
         x:DataType="viewmodel:DaySingleViewModel"
         Title="{Binding Title}">

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Entry
            Text="{Binding Title}" />

        <Label 
            Text="{Binding Title}" />

        <Label
            Text="Test" />

        <Button
            Text="Load Days" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

The VIEWMODEL is called "DaySingleViewModel" located inside a ViewModel directory. I've got multiple fields and methods, but I'm stripping them out to keep this question lean.

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using CommunityToolkit.Diagnostics;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using MauiCalendar.Model;
using MauiCalendar.Services;


namespace MauiCalendar.ViewModel
{
    [ObservableObject]
    public partial class DaySingleViewModel 
    {
        public DaySingleViewModel()
        { }

        [ObservableProperty]
        string title = "Starting Value";
    }
}
```

The above code outputs the following:

[image: The bound DataView text does not appear.]

Would anyone with more experience be willing to take a look at what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: First, have you "Registered" the view and viewmodel? [Intellisense works because of `x:DataType`, but that is NOT what connects the two at runtime.] If so, then second, you have three xaml elements binding to the same property, Title. Perhaps that is somehow causing an issue.  Remove all uses of `{Binding Title}`, except the one in `Label`. Does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code, and you need add `BindingContext` to **connect** the `View` with `ViewModel` firstly. Here's the code snippet below for your reference. Just keep the code neat and easy to understand.

**View:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiCalendar.View.DaySingleView">
    
    <VerticalStackLayout>

        <Entry Text="{Binding Title}" />

        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />

        <Label Text="Test"/>

        <Button Text="Load Days"/>

    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**View's code-behind:**

```
using MauiCalendar.ViewModel; 
namespace MauiCalendar.View;

public partial class DaySingleView : ContentPage
{
      public DaySingleView()
      {
        BindingContext = new DaySingleViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
      }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel; 

namespace MauiCalendar.ViewModel
{

    [ObservableObject]
    public partial class DaySingleViewModel
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        string title = "Starting  Value";

        public DaySingleViewModel() { }
    }
}
```

**Starting Page:**

```
using MauiCalendar.View; 

namespace MauiCalendar;

public partial class App : Application
{
      public App()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new DaySingleView();
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This is how I used to bind...in the CS page. I thought it would be better in MAUI to bind via the XAML.  Now I need to figure out where I went wrong.  Thanks again!